# (Adopt)OpenJDK installation package including WebStart and JavaFX

Tags: open-source, java

I am searching for an **open Java-installation-package that contains WebStart functionality and JavaFX components** so that I can run JavaFX applications via WebStart.

I want to replace Oracle-Java 8 with an open Java-installation to avoid Oracle-licensing.

The preferred open-Java would be AdoptOpenJDK, but as I have seen, there is WebStart in version 8 only, where JavaFX is only in version 11.
I'd need both in one.

For a specific version of AdoptOpenJDK-8 I've already managed it to add JavaFX components. But since it is high effort to put this together each time a new AdoptOpenJDK version is released, I am looking for a complete solution, maybe also in another openJDK-package.

Best regards and thank you in advance for any hint.

Answer (score 1):

## Adoptium

*AdoptOpenJDK* is now known as [*Adoptium*](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/adoptium), after moving to the [Eclipse Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_Foundation). But keep using the https://adoptopenjdk.net web site during their transition.

Adoptium offers many variations of Java implementations, for various CPU architectures, host OSes, and such. But none of them include the JavaFX libraries necessary to run a JavaFX ([OpenJFX](https://openjfx.io)) app.

You can download the JavaFX/OpenJFX library, and install on the user’s machine, somewhere on the Java classpath. Or you can obtain a Java implementation that comes with the JavaFX/OpenJFX library bundled.

## Other vendors bundling JavaFX

Two other vendors provide such a Java implementation,  also based largely on the OpenJDK project as are the Adoptium products:

- *ZuluFX* by Azul Systems
- *LibericaFX* by BellSoft

These are noted in this flowchart I made to help guide you in choosing a vendor for a Java implementation.

[image: Flowchart guiding you in choosing a vendor for a Java 11 implementation]

## Java Web Start

As for [Java Web Start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start) & JNLP, that technology is being phased out by Oracle. Read this white paper from Oracle, [*Java Client Roadmap Update*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdatev2020may-6548840.pdf), dated 2020-05.

An open-source alternative implementation of JNLP is underway at [*OpenWebStart*](https://openwebstart.com). I know nothing about that product.

Oracle recommends you make a build of your app for every host OS you intend to support. In each build, use *jlink* and other such tools to bundle the parts of the JDK needed to run your JavaFX app. Your app bundle will then be ready-to-run standalone, like any other double-clickable native app. Use similar distribution models as you would for a native app: manual downloads, installed via enterprise PC management software, or app stores.